# Getting mouse click position on image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I wrote below code to get co-ordinate of x/y in JAVASCRIPT , it's not working .

I want to create a color picker using this image 
when ever some one click on button pick color then it prompts a window with color and button cancel , When user clicked on  image than i need to find x/y co-ordinate so that i can specify which color it is .

Problem is that these alerts are not working

```
alert(e.clientX - offsetl);
alert(e.clientY - offsett);

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#dialogoverlay{
    display: none;
    opacity: .8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox{
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius:5px; 
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogboxhead{background:white;height:40px;margin:10px;}
#text {float:left; text-align:center;margin:10px; font-size:19px;}
#cancel{float:left;margin:9px;}
#image{
    margin-top:0px;
    padding:10px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function CustomAlert(){
    this.render = function(dialog){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
    }
    this.cancel = function(){
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
function position(e){
    var offsetl = document.getElementById('image').offsetLeft;
    var offsett = document.getElementById('image').offsetTop; 
    alert(offsetl);
    alert(offsett);
    alert(e.clientX - offsetl);
    alert(e.clientY - offsett);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
    <div id="dialogboxhead">
     <p id="text">Select color</p>
     <input type="button" onClick="Alert.cancel()" id="cancel" name="Cancel" value="Cancel"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <img id="image" src="color.png" onClick="position()"/>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="Alert.render('Hello World');" >pick color </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6J5TL/

Comment: Thanks . I forgot  adding event as argument in function call .

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use jQuery and attach click event handler in you image. The event object return in jQuery include two properties, pageX and pageY. This properties contains mouse position relative to the top edge of the document ([jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)). The code look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img#image').click(position);
});

function position(e) {
    var offsetX = e.pageX,
        offsetY = e.page;
}
```

The sample is in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zV3dH/.

I hope this help you.

Comment: But the problem is still there , in finding color according to co-ordinate .So I am creating small button 25*25 px and  this is much easier than using image to pick a color .

Comment: Mmm, You're using HTML5. If so, you can draw the image in a canvas, and use canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData to get information <http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code buddy.. Sure it works

```
 function getClickPos(e) {
     return {x:e.clientX,y:e.clientY};
 }
```

Now u can use it like this:

```
document.querySelector("#img").onclick = function(e) {
 var pos= getClickPos(e);
 alert(pos.x);
 };
```